# Nhibernate load overwriting values before SaveorUpdate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am currently having problems getting my Update function working, the function first loads an entity using `session.Load()` and then uses `session.SaveorUpdate()`.

My problem is that if I do not load the session first nhibernate will not know the the relationships and therefore try and insert data which is already there and when I do load the entity first, the updated entity is overwritten by the data already in the database.

```
public void Update(T Entity, bool load)
{
    using(ISession session = this.helper.GetSession())
    {
        using(ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            if(load)
            {
                session.Load(Entity, Entity.ID);
            }

            session.SaveOrUpdate(Entity);
            transaction.Commit();
            session.Flush(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to add the tag for the **correct** language yourself.

Comment: @Frankie_C Sorry I am sure I put C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell:

> - load object and then bind it with new values *(changes will be persisted on `session.Flush()` without any explicit `Update()` call)* or
> - create new C# instance with bounded values, including ID, and call `session.Update(myInstance)`

The more complex answer could be found in one of the doc chapters:

#### [9.4.2. Updating detached objects](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-updating-detached)

> Many applications need to retrieve an object in one transaction, send it to the UI layer for manipulation, then save the changes in a new transaction. (Applications that use this kind of approach in a high-concurrency environment usually use versioned data to ensure transaction isolation.) This approach requires a slightly different programming model to the one described in the last section. NHibernate supports this model by providing the method **`ISession.Update()`**.

```
// in the first session
Cat cat = firstSession.Load<Cat>(catId);
Cat potentialMate = new Cat();
firstSession.Save(potentialMate);

// in a higher tier of the application
cat.Mate = potentialMate;

// later, in a new session
secondSession.Update(cat);  // update cat
secondSession.Update(mate); // update mate
```

> The usage and semantics of **`SaveOrUpdate()`** seems to be confusing for new users. Firstly, so long as you are not trying to use instances from one session in another new session, you should not need to use **`Update()`** or **`SaveOrUpdate()`**. Some whole applications will never use either of these methods.
>
> Usually `Update()` or `SaveOrUpdate()` are used in the following scenario:
>
> - the application loads an object in the first session
> - the object is passed up to the UI tier
> - some modifications are made to the object
> - the object is passed back down to the business logic tier
> - the application persists these modifications by calling Update() in a second session

So, we can get an instance of some entity in one session... and close that session. Such **object could be even totally brand new C# instance** - with all its properties being bounded by some upper layer *(e.g. MVC binder, or Web API formatter)*

Later, we can use that instance and call **`session.Update(myInstance)`**. NHibernate will take the ID of that entity and issue the proper update statement.

Another way could be to call Merge:

> The last case can be avoided by using **`Merge(Object o)`**. This method copies the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently associated with the session, it will be loaded. The method returns the persistent instance. If the given instance is unsaved or does not exist in the database, NHibernate will save it and return it as a newly persistent instance. Otherwise, the given instance does not become associated with the session. In most applications with detached objects, you need both methods, `SaveOrUpdate()` and `Merge()`.

read more in [the doc](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-updating-detached)

Comment: Thank you Radim, this was a very insightful and helpful answer. With the help of your suggestions above I was able to get my method to work and now have more of an understanding of nhibernate.

Comment: That is brilliant information. Enjoy mighty NHibernate ;)